# Swampdragon settings.js

Tags: django, swampdragon

Where I can find this file?

I tried to use [this](http://swampdragon.net/tutorial/part-1-here-be-dragons-and-thats-a-good-thing/) tutorial and just copy paste most of all examples. But when I'm trying to launch this app, I have an error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Server is trying to load settings.js file from http://domain.name/settings.js, but that file doesn't exist. What is this?

Comment: They changed that.. now it's not required .. but what's your version..? do you have this `{% load swampdragon_tags %}` ?

Comment: Last version of swampdragon. Yes, I used swampdragon_tags. And if I delete {% swampdragon_settings %}, I have next error: Cannot read property 'endpoint' of undefined. It's a swampdragon.js on line endpoint = window.swampdragon_settings.endpoint.

Comment: Also, console.log(window.swampdragon_host);
    console.log(window.swampdragon_settings); result undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add
server.py

```
import os
from swampdragon.swampdragon_server import run_server
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')    
run_server()
```

and run `python server.py`

Comment: It worked for me. Also don't forget to add `{% swampdragon_settings %} <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'swampdragon/js/dist/swampdragon.js' %}"></script>`